# Android: Start AnimatedVectorDrawable animation mid way

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable, objectanimator, animatedvectordrawable

**Background**: I am looking to create a countdown timer similar to the native Clock app's Timer. I am very new to Android animations so I have been evaluating various solutions. I was looking to go with `AnimatedVectorDrawable`s but hit a roadblock.

**Question:** is there any way to start an animation on an `AnimationVectorDrawable` mid way through instead of from the beginning? If not, what is the best practice for creating such an animation?

**Use case:** I want the countdown animation to stay in sync with minute marks on the clock so when the user displays it at a time that isn't on the minute mark, the countdown animation starts mid way through so it finishes on the minute mark.

**XML Layout for `animated-vector`:**

```
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:name="vector"
            android:width="26dp"
            android:height="26dp"
            android:viewportWidth="26"
            android:viewportHeight="26">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:pathData="M 13 1 C 6.373 1 1 6.373 1 13 C 1 19.627 6.373 25 13 25 C 19.627 25 25 19.627 25 13 C 25 6.373 19.627 1 13 1 Z"
                android:strokeWidth="1"
                android:fillType="evenOdd"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                    android:duration="2950"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                    android:startOffset="2950"
                    android:duration="50"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:duration="1900"
                    android:valueFrom="#818181"
                    android:valueTo="#f0c473"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="strokeAlpha"
                    android:duration="3000"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:startOffset="1900"
                    android:duration="600"
                    android:valueFrom="#f0c473"
                    android:valueTo="#e06969"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:startOffset="2500"
                    android:duration="450"
                    android:valueFrom="#e06969"
                    android:valueTo="#e06969"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="strokeColor"
                    android:startOffset="2950"
                    android:duration="50"
                    android:valueFrom="#e06969"
                    android:valueTo="#818181"
                    android:valueType="colorType"
                    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Comment: Does your animation only encompass one tick (duration <= 1 second)?

Comment: The animation actually runs for 30 seconds. It doesn't have clock hands, but rather is a circular path that starts full and slowly trims the path back until it is gone

Comment: Your xml has some ObjectAnimators. ObjectAnimator inherits a method [`setCurrentPlaytime()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentPlayTime(long)) from ValueAnimator. AnimatorSet also has this method but only from API level 26. So basically it's possible.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look into something like that. I unfortunately have to support back to API 21 but it seems like I could possibly manually handle this. Would this be a preferred method over something like a custom `View` with a `ValueAnimator`? Like I said, I am an animation n00b so any direction is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Using a custom View sounds tempting but I have the feeling that using a ValueAnimator with an [ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener.html) to toggle the various path properties programmatically may be better in your case. That's what I would attempt to do first. It would enable you to use setCurrentPlaytime() on your single ValueAnimator (possible from API level 11)

Comment: Thanks! Would that have issues since I not only need to trim the path, but also change the color once the duration hits various values. Could you possibly provide some sample code as to what you are talking about? I think I have a solid understanding (and am starting to play around with it now) but want to make sure I am heading down the right path.

Comment: For changing the color: consider using a ColorFilter. About the sample code: the reason I did not write an answer at once is that I'm not sure that I can find the time. I'd like to, because it's an interesting question, and I'll try to do so this weekend. But I won't promise anything.

Comment: Thanks and no worries! I know how that goes. Possibly stupid question but how can you get access to the `ObjectAnimators` (or ideally the `AnimatorSet`) from either the `AnimatedVectorDrawable` or the `ImageView`? I don't seem to see any documentation in the APIs that hints at this being possible. I think I will need to keep an `AnimatorSet` since I have to have the timer animate refilling to full at the end of the timer.

Comment: You're right, it seems to be impossible to get the ObjectAnimators from the AnimatedVectorDrawable. BTW I found a [library](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2018/03/introducing-kyrie-animated-vector-drawables.html) which may be helpful (did not try it myself yet but I appreciate the author's other publications very much)

Comment: Nice! that looks really cool and I have been reading and using a good amt of resources from that guy. I unfortunately can't bring in the library for a couple of reasons but that looks really cool! I got everything working other than starting the animation mid-way but I am not sure if that is possible using an `AnimatedVectorDrawable` because of what we have discussed above.

Comment: I'm also rather pessimistic because you can't access the Animators from outside. But Android is an open source project, so another option could be taking the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/eb034fb/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.java) of AnimatedVectorDrawable and adding your own code (this way you can access all the ObjectAnimators)

Comment: Yeah, its looking like the only options are to take the code and copy/paste it into the project or to use reflections to access the private variable... Neither of these seem desirable to me so I may have to go another route unless I am missing something.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Today I tried to copy-paste everything into my own AVD class and make it work but I had to patch the code and especially the VectorDrawable  method getTargetByName() seems to have been there around 5.0 but it's gone today. Now I wonder where do I find a repo with the current source code? I know it's a bit of a hack but because there is that useful method setCurrentPlaytime() for level 26+ one would only have to cover a limited number of older versions with the custom AVD. But no luck so far :(

Comment: Damn, yeah I played around with it for a while too but ultimately decided to move over to using a custom view drawing it on a canvas using a `ValueAnimator`. Everything seems to be working and I just need to build the rewind animation. Thanks for the investigation! I really hope this is something Google looks into in the future to better `AnimatedVectorDrawable`s.